# NS Predicate with Multiple Text Fields

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, nspredicate

I'm working on a Core Data application that lets users add data to a table view. Each object has three different attributes. After typing the attributes into a text field, the user then saves the data objects; where they can be seen in a Table View.

I've also implemented a search function that lets the user search for their object based on their attributes using NSPredicate. I looked at the [this](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/03/filtering-fun-with-predicates/) guide and this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14742/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-how-to-work-with-relations-and-predicates) for info on how to do this.Each attribute corresponds to a predicate as shown in the code below.

My problem is that users are only able to search for objects based on the first attribute. So, when they go to enter something in the text field for the first attribute, the search returns the correct results, and each attribute is displayed in the text fields. If the user tries to search using the second or third attribute, then nothing is returned.

```
NSPredicate *predAttOne =
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name CONTAINS %@)",
 _one.text];
[request setPredicate:predAttOne];


//////////////PROBLEM CODE///////////////

//If the code below is commented out, the user is able to search using 
//the first attribute successfully, and al the data attributes are shown 
//in the text fields. If it's not commented out, no data is found.

NSPredicate *predAttTwo =
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(mint CONTAINS %@)",
 _two.text];
[request setPredicate:predAttTwo];

NSPredicate *predAttThree =
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(year CONTAINS %@)",
 _three.text];
[request setPredicate:predAttThree];
```

Does anyone know how I can use predicates to search based on different attributes? I'm aware of compound predicates, but I'm not sure that's what I need for this situation.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use all three and combine the results.

Comment: Hi @CrimsonChris, I'm not exactly sure what you mean; how would I combine the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do predicate like this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name CONTAINS %@) OR (mint CONTAINS %@) OR (year CONTAINS %@)",  _two.text, _two.text, _two.text];
```

Comment: I have deleted the second one. It's not valid predicate format.

Comment: Ahh! @Allan, I did just notice something, now if I try to search for something that does not exist, it returns back every object that is currently stored.

Comment: You can check every search text key, maybe it satisfy some of the conditions. You can log the actual predicate format result and check it. `NSLog(@"format: %@", [predicate predicateFormat])`.

Comment: I figured it out; accidentally switched some lines around. All working fine now, thanks again!